# k times left rotation of array

Tags: c++, algorithm, array

Left rotate array (a), k times, n is size of array.

I know, we can calculate n, but prototype is mentioned in respective question.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<int> array_left_rotation(vector<int> a, int n, int k) {

    vector<int> a1(n);
    int np = -1;
    for(int i = 0 ;i<n ; i++)
    {

      np = ((i - k) + n)%n; //new position

      a1[np] = a[i];

    }

    return a1;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
```

Don't use `using namespace`. It will import hundreds of names, and you only need a single one of them.

```
vector<int> array_left_rotation(vector<int> a, int n, int k) {
```

Write `std::vector` instead of the unqualified `vector`.

Pass `a` as `const std::vector<int> &a`. The `const &` avoids making a complete copy of the vector. Using a reference (`&`) for accessing the vector makes your program faster.

```
    vector<int> a1(n);
    int np = -1;
```

Since you only need the `np` variable inside the loop, don't declare it outside. This way, you also don't need the `-1`, which serves no purpose in this program.

```
    for(int i = 0 ;i<n ; i++)
```

Leave a space after the `for`, since it is a keyword and not a function name. Don't leave a space before the semicolon. Leave a space after it. Leave spaces around comparison operators.

```
    {

      np = ((i - k) + n)%n; //new position
```

Avoid the comment. Rather call your variable `newpos` instead of `np`.

```
      a1[np] = a[i];

    }

    return a1;

}
```

Remove the empty line before a closing brace. It just wastes space.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe your code doesnt work. If you swap N elements pairwise you end up with the identical vector right? You should only loop until n/2.
2. Do not use `namespace std;` It is a bad practice that you should stop sooner than later.
3. Use descriptive names. n, k, np are not understandable by themselves.
4. Finally, c++ now knows std::iter_swap, which directly the values of 2 iterators. so you might wanna use that.

Comment: I don't see any swapping in the code.

Comment: The question is named left rotate an array, which kind of implies that the data can be changed

Comment: It doesn't change the vector, and it returns a vector, which kind of implies that the data is not intended to be changed.

Comment: The question is whether the copy is intended or just a bad design